# jQuery check the parent checkbox if the child checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, input

I want to make a logic that if a child checkbox is checked, it checks the parent checkbox too. The input can parent, child and both:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[$counter]" class="parent" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[$counter]" class="child" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[$counter]" class="parent child" />
```

This structure:

- 1

  - 2
  - 3
- 4

  - 5

    - 6
    - 7

will be look like this:

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[1]" class="parent" />
    </td>
    <td>
     .
     .
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[2]" class="child" />
    </td>
    <td>
     .
     .
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[3]" class="child" />
    </td>
    <td>
     .
     .
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[4]" class="parent" />
    </td>
    <td>
     .
     .
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[5]" class="child parent" />
    </td>
    <td>
     .
     .
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[6]" class="child" />
    </td>
    <td>
     .
     .
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[7]" class="child" />
    </td>
    <td>
     .
     .
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want if I check 3, it checks 1 and if I check 6 it checks 5 and 4, too.

Also the checkboxes are in separate table rows, becouse I want to show some information structured in table next to the checkbox.

Can you show me a script what does it? I tried this, but it's not working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.child').change(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).closest('input.parent:checkbox').attr('checked', true);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: is it li ui structure?

Comment: `checkbox` not `chechkbox`

Comment: @programtreasures it's table tr td structure

Comment: @Pedram sorry, typo

Comment: Your `html` `structure ` is important, because these answers works here without any table, you need to update your question with table structure.

Comment: @Pedram Thank you and sorry, I edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The checkboxes are not parent-child relationship, thus the method [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) will not work as it traverse's up starting from itself.

I would recommend you to assign classes with `TR` element and also attach event handler with them, traversing DOM will be easy.

```
<tr class="parent">...</tr>
<tr class="child">...</tr>
```

You could use combination of [`.prevAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/prevall/) and [`.first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/) to get the targeted `TR`, then use `.find()` to get the checkbox.

Additionally, If you want to fire the change event `trigger()` method can be used.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.child').on('change', ':checkbox', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      var currentRow = $(this).closest('tr');
      var targetedRow = currentRow.prevAll('.parent').first();
      var targetedCheckbox = targetedRow.find(':checkbox');
      targetedCheckbox.prop('checked', true).trigger('change');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table class="table">
  <tr class="parent">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[1]" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="child">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[2]" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="child">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[3]" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="parent">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[4]" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="child parent">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[5]" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="child">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[6]" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="child">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[7]" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i used your code it works fine when checking the child input.I have two problems first when i uncheck all child input i want the parent input to be unchecked and second when i uncheck the parent input i want all child inputs to be unchecked can that be done ?

Answer (score 0):

Try below script,

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function(e) {
  $(this).siblings('ul').find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', this.checked);
  $(this).parentsUntil('input[type=checkbox]').children("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', this.checked);
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With your current `html` structure you need make a link between `childs` and `parents`, for example with `data` attribute, now it works with any `html` structure, `table`, `ul li` or without these.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input.child').on('change', function() {
    var data = $(this).data('name');

    if (this.checked) {
      $('input.parent:checkbox[data-name="' + data + '"]').prop('checked', true);
      $('input.parent:checkbox[data-parent="' + data + '"]').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $('input.parent:checkbox[data-name="' + data + '"]').prop('checked', false);
      $('input.parent:checkbox[data-parent="' + data + '"]').prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
});

/* Optional, This is what I added for better look */

$('.child').each(function() {
  $(this).parent().css({
    paddingLeft: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#c0c0c0'
  });
});

$('.parent').each(function() {
  $(this).parent().css({
    backgroundColor: 'black'
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[1]" class="parent" data-name="chck-1" />
    </td>
    <td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[2]" class="child" data-name="chck-1" />
    </td>
    <td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[3]" class="child" data-name="chck-1" />
    </td>
    <td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[4]" class="parent" data-name="chck-2" />
    </td>
    <td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[5]" class="child parent" data-name="chck-2" data-parent="chck-3" />
    </td>
    <td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[6]" class="child" data-name="chck-3" />
    </td>
    <td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[7]" class="child" data-name="chck-3" />
    </td>
    <td>
  </tr>
</table>
```